# Странная ошибка с AnsiString и TSTringList

Tags: c++builder, синтаксический-анализ

Есть у меня следующий код:

```
    AnsiString str = "194.106.196.100:28960";

    TStringList* ipport = new TStringList;
    ipport->StrictDelimiter = true;
    ipport->Delimiter = ':';
    ipport->DelimitedText = str;

    char *srvip = (ipport->Strings[0]).t_str();
    int srvport = (ipport->Strings[1]).ToInt();

    //Memo1->Lines->Add("Str: " + AnsiString(str));
    Memo1->Lines->Add("IP: " + AnsiString(srvip));
    Memo1->Lines->Add("Port: " + AnsiString(srvport));

    delete ipport;
    ipport = NULL;
```

Для проверки эти переменные добавляю в мемо, и выходит интересная картина - в мемо у меня пишется:
IP: 194.106.196.10
Port: 28960
А картина интересная потому, что если ip сделать как 194.106.196.1000:28960 или 194.106.196.10:28960, то в мемо покажется ИМЕННО этот IP-шник... Почему так? Уже всю голову сломал. И как сделать, что бы нормально всё таки писалось?

Comment: Поэкспериментировав, пришел к выводу, что любое трехзначное число там будет обрезаться... че за фигня?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не лениться, а найти позицию ':' и разрезать строку руками старыми добрыми методами.

**UPD** Странный эффект наверняка связан с короткоживучестью экземпляра строки, возвращаемой из TStringsList для которой вы вызываете t_str. Видимо, она возвращает указатель на строку, а не копию, а потом сразу уничтожается.. в результате указатель ссылается на мусор.

Comment: Но если я вместо сто напишу 1000, он мне тысячу и напишет. Если 10, напишет 10. Если 100 так и оставлю, то обрежет последний символ. Странно это как-то.  
А из старых добрых strtok юзать лучше, на Ваш взгляд?:)

Comment: Ничего странного... если данные уже уничтожены, то они могут быть затёрты другими данными произвольным образом. На старых добрых будет намного эффективнее и выглядеть будет намного короче. А ещё лучше написать свой собственный утилитный метод split и везде его использовать.

Comment: Сделал проще:  

    AnsiString s = ipport->Strings[0];  
    char *srvip = s.c_str();

Answer (score 0):

Зачем простой задаче такие сложности?
Я бы сделал так:

```
AnsiString str = "194.106.196.100:28960";
Memo1->Lines->Add("IP: " + str.SubString(0,str.Pos(":")-1));
Memo1->Lines->Add("Port: " + str.SubString(str.Pos(":")+1,100));
```

А если это в цикле, чтобы сэкономить время выполнения, то заранее определил бы позицию в переменную: `int i =  str.Pos(":");`